# Writing Custom Layer (3D RoI Pooling) using Keras in R

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, lidar

Using R, I would like to produce a Keras custom layer that performs 3D Region of Interest (RoI) Pooling. My 3D RoI Pooling function works as expected outside of an R6Class KerasLayer, but I am having trouble integrating it into a Custom Layer. I am not sure if I am using autograph correctly in the below example. I am under the impressing that for me to use the R functionalities (i.e. for loop) in the "call" section of the custom layer I am required to wrap the function in autograph.

Is the below custom layer for applying a 3D RoI Pooling (without training weights) appropriate syntex for an R user of Keras?

The input for the 3d_RoI_Pool layer includes:

(i) output layer from a VNet model,

- shape=(None, 16, 16, 40, 1)

(ii) tensor defining the "index" for cropping the input layer to the extent of each RoI,

```
  - tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1, 1, 6) dtype=float64, numpy=array([[[ 5.,  5.,  4.,  5., 10., 20.]]])
```

(iii) output dimension for the pooled 3D RoIs.

- In this case its c(1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1) for c(Batch_Size, RoI_Size, X, Y, Z, Channels)

Below are some questions that I am unclear about:

- I initially apply layer_cropping_3d to crop each RoI but am not sure if custom layer is allowed to use available R Keras layers? For this reason, in code I performed my own cropping.
- Is it the correct use of autograph within custom layer?
- Should I instead use the layer_lambda() for such a function (i.e. Wraps arbitrary expression as a layer), given that I do not have trainable weights in the 3D_RoI_Pooling layer?

Below is the Code that gets the output layer from a V-Net CNN and prepares inputs for the custom layer:

```
  # FINAL LAYERS OF V_Net
  Output_shortcut = up1_DeConv
  Final_Conv <- up1_Concat %>%
    # 1st
    layer_conv_3d(filters = Filter_Start, kernel_size = Kernel_Conv_Size, padding = "same", name = "Final_Conv") %>%
    layer_batch_normalization() %>%
    layer_activation("relu")

  Final_Conv <- layer_add(c(Final_Conv, Output_shortcut), name = "Final_Conv_ResNet")

  # PREPARE INPUT FOR CUSTOM LAYER
  n_RoI <- 1 
  Batch_Size <- 1 

  Table_RoI <- list(list(c(5, 5), c(4, 5), c(10, 20)))
  Table_RoI <- array_reshape(unlist(Table_RoI), c(Batch_Size,n_RoI,6), order="F")
  Table_RoI <- tf$Variable(Table_RoI, tf$int16)

  output_dim <- c(Batch_Size, n_RoI, 5,5,5, as.numeric(dim(Final_Conv)[5]))

  # FEED CUSTOM LAYER TO CNN
  Final_Conv2 <- Final_Conv %>% layer_3D_ROI_pooled(Table_RoI=Table_RoI, output_dim= output_dim)
```

Below is the actual 3D RoI Pooling Custom Layer that generates an error:

```
# 3D ROIpooled_Layer (R KERAS )
ROIpooled_Layer <- R6::R6Class("KerasLayer",
                                inherit = KerasLayer,
                                public = list(
                                  Table_RoI = NULL,
                                  output_dim = NULL, 

                                  ###############
                                  # INITIALISE
                                  ###############

                                  initialize = function(Table_RoI, output_dim) {
                                    self$Table_RoI = Table_RoI
                                    self$output_dim = output_dim
                                    },

                                  ###############
                                  # CALL FUNCTION   ROIpooled_Function <-
                                  ###############
                                  call = autograph(function(x, mask = NULL,
                                                            Table_RoI,
                                                            output_dim) {

                                    ## Input_L ROI_Table 
                                    n_Batch <- output_dim[1]
                                    n_RoI <- output_dim[2]
                                    Channels <- output_dim[6]

                                    for(r in 1:n_RoI){


                                        # layer_cropping_3d(Input_L, cropping = list(list(as.numeric(Table_RoI[,r,1]), as.numeric(Table_RoI[,r,2])), 
                                        #                                                               list(as.numeric(Table_RoI[,r,3]), as.numeric(Table_RoI[,r,4])), 
                                        #                                                               list(as.numeric(Table_RoI[,r,5]), as.numeric(Table_RoI[,r,6]))))

                                      RoI_Cropped <-x[,(as.numeric(Table_RoI[,r,1])+1):(dim(feature_map_T)[2]-as.numeric(Table_RoI[,r,2])),
                                                                  (as.numeric(Table_RoI[,r,3])+1):(dim(feature_map_T)[3]-as.numeric(Table_RoI[,r,4])),
                                                                  (as.numeric(Table_RoI[,r,5])+1):(dim(feature_map_T)[4]-as.numeric(Table_RoI[,r,6])),]

                                      RoI_X_Res <- as.array(k_shape(RoI_Cropped)[2])
                                      RoI_Y_Res <- as.array(k_shape(RoI_Cropped)[3])
                                      RoI_Z_Res <- as.array(k_shape(RoI_Cropped)[4])

                                      New_X_Res <- as.array(output_dim[3])
                                      New_Y_Res <- as.array(output_dim[4])
                                      New_Z_Res <- as.array(output_dim[5])

                                      X_step = RoI_X_Res / New_X_Res    
                                      Y_step = RoI_Y_Res  / New_Y_Res  
                                      Z_step = RoI_Z_Res  / New_Z_Res  

                                      for(ch in 1:Channels) { 
                                        print(paste("ch", ch))
                                        for (k in 1:New_Z_Res) { 
                                          print(paste("k", k))
                                          for (j in 1:New_Y_Res) { 
                                            print(paste("j", j, "k", k))
                                            for (i in 1:New_X_Res) { 
                                              # INDEX X
                                              Index_Xstart <- floor((i-1)*X_step+1)
                                              if(i+1 <= RoI_X_Res){
                                                Index_Xend <- floor((i)*X_step)
                                              }else{
                                                Index_Xend <- RoI_X_Res
                                              }
                                              # INDEX Y
                                              Index_Ystart <-  floor((j-1)*Y_step+1) 
                                              if(j+1 <= RoI_Y_Res){
                                                Index_Yend <- floor((j)*Y_step)
                                              }else{
                                                Index_Yend <-RoI_Y_Res
                                              }
                                              # INDEX Z        
                                              Index_Zstart <-  floor((k-1)*Z_step+1) 
                                              if(k+1 <= RoI_Z_Res){
                                                Index_Zend <- floor((k)*Z_step)
                                              }else{
                                                Index_Zend <-RoI_Z_Res
                                              }
                                              Max_Pool_X_Value <- as.array(k_max(RoI_Cropped[n_Batch,Index_Xstart:Index_Xend, Index_Ystart:Index_Yend, Index_Zstart:Index_Zend,ch])) # ADD BATCH AND CHANNEL LAYERS
                                              RoI_Pooled_Array[,r,i,j,k,ch] <- Max_Pool_X_Value
                                            }# i LOOP
                                          } # j LOOP 
                                        } # k Loop
                                      } #Ch LOOP 
                                    } # r LOOP (ROI)
                                    feature_map_ROIpooled <- tf$Variable(RoI_Pooled_Array, tf$int16) # ??? NOT SURE IF RETURN NEEDS TO BE A VARIABLE

                                    return (feature_map_ROIpooled)

                                  }), # END OF AUTO, # END OF CALL ... AUTOGRAPH FUNCTION

                                  ##############
                                  # OUTPUT SHAPE
                                  ##############

                                  compute_output_shape = function(input_shape) { 
                                    list(self$output_dim) 
                                    }
                                )
                              )
# 
###############################
# Create layer wrapper function
###############################

layer_3D_ROI_pooled <- function(object, Table_RoI, output_dim, name = NULL, trainable = TRUE) {
  create_layer(ROIpooled_Layer, object, list(Table_RoI = Table_RoI, 
                                              output_dim = as.integer(output_dim), 
                                              name = name,
                                              trainable = FALSE
                                            ))
}
```

ERROR:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
   The R function's signature must not contains esoteric Python-incompatible constructs. Detailed traceback: SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument (<string>, line 3)
```

Any help/insight/clarity would be appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Dom

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct protocol to answer own question but I think I have a working 3D RoI pooling Custom Layer to share. Many mistakes in above but most notable change is in the for loop.... I think I needed to first generate a list of tensors that represent each pooled RoI and then re-shape it to the desired output shape.

```
################################################################################################
# ROI_3D_pooled_Layer (Custom layer class)
##########################################
ROI_3D_pooled_Layer <- R6::R6Class("KerasLayer",

                                   inherit = KerasLayer,

                                   public = list(
                                     List_RoI = NULL,
                                     output_dim = NULL, 

                                     initialize = function(List_RoI, output_dim) {
                                       self$List_RoI = List_RoI
                                       self$output_dim = output_dim
                                     },

                                     call = function(x, mask = NULL) {   
                                       List_RoI <- self$List_RoI
                                       output_dim <- self$output_dim

                                       # EXTRACT INFORMATION ON OUTPUT DIMENSION
                                       n_Batch <- as.integer(output_dim[1])
                                       n_RoIs <- as.integer(output_dim[2])
                                       n_Channels <- as.integer(output_dim[6])

                                       New_X_Res <- as.numeric(output_dim[3])
                                       New_Y_Res <- as.numeric(output_dim[4])
                                       New_Z_Res <- as.numeric(output_dim[5])

                                       input_shape <- dim(x)

                                       # EMPTY LIST TO STORE TENSORS
                                       output_list = list()
                                       for(r in 1:n_RoIs){ # LOOP RoIs
                                         # GET one RoI AND CROP INPUT LAYER
                                         if(n_RoIs > 1){
                                           oneList_RoI <- List_RoI[[r]]
                                         }else{
                                           oneList_RoI <- List_RoI
                                         }

                                         RoI_Cropped <-x[,(oneList_RoI[[1]][1]+1):(as.numeric(input_shape[2])-oneList_RoI[[1]][2]),
                                                         (oneList_RoI[[2]][1]+1):(as.numeric(input_shape[3])-oneList_RoI[[2]][2]),
                                                         (oneList_RoI[[3]][1]+1):(as.numeric(input_shape[4])-oneList_RoI[[3]][1]),]

                                         # GET RoI Dimensions for XYZ
                                         RoI_X_Res <- as.numeric(dim(RoI_Cropped)[2])
                                         RoI_Y_Res <- as.numeric(dim(RoI_Cropped)[3])
                                         RoI_Z_Res <- as.numeric(dim(RoI_Cropped)[4])

                                         # CALCULATE STEPS IN ALL DIMENSIONS FOR POOLING
                                         X_step = RoI_X_Res / New_X_Res    
                                         Y_step = RoI_Y_Res  / New_Y_Res  
                                         Z_step = RoI_Z_Res  / New_Z_Res  

                                         for(ch in 1:n_Channels) { # LOOP CHANNEL
                                           for (k in 1:New_Z_Res) { # LOOP Z
                                             for (j in 1:New_Y_Res) { # LOOP Y
                                               for (i in 1:New_X_Res) { # LOOP X
                                                 # INDEX X
                                                 Index_Xstart <- floor((i-1)*X_step+1)
                                                 if(i+1 <= RoI_X_Res){
                                                   Index_Xend <- floor((i)*X_step)
                                                 }else{
                                                   Index_Xend <- RoI_X_Res
                                                 }
                                                 # INDEX Y
                                                 Index_Ystart <-  floor((j-1)*Y_step+1) 
                                                 if(j+1 <= RoI_Y_Res){
                                                   Index_Yend <- floor((j)*Y_step)
                                                 }else{
                                                   Index_Yend <-RoI_Y_Res
                                                 }
                                                 # INDEX Z        
                                                 Index_Zstart <-  floor((k-1)*Z_step+1) 
                                                 if(k+1 <= RoI_Z_Res){
                                                   Index_Zend <- floor((k)*Z_step)
                                                 }else{
                                                   Index_Zend <-RoI_Z_Res
                                                 }

                                                 # MAX POOL VOLUME FOR EACH ELEMENT IN FINAL LAYER AND PUT IN EMPTY ARRAY
                                                 Max_Pool_X_Value <-k_max(RoI_Cropped[,Index_Xstart:Index_Xend, Index_Ystart:Index_Yend, Index_Zstart:Index_Zend,ch])

                                                 # APPEND EACH RoI_Pooled element into a list
                                                 output_list <- list.append(output_list, Max_Pool_X_Value)
                                               }# i LOOP
                                             } # j LOOP 
                                           } # k Loop
                                         } #Ch LOOP 
                                       } # r LOOP (ROI)

                                       # STACK THE OUTPUT LIST AND RESHAPE TO THE DESIRED OUTPUT SIZE 
                                       output_Stack <- k_stack(output_list, axis = 1)
                                       feature_map_ROIpooled <- k_reshape(output_Stack, shape = c(n_Batch, n_RoIs, New_X_Res, New_Y_Res, New_Z_Res, n_Channels))
                                       return (feature_map_ROIpooled)
                                     },
                                     compute_output_shape = function(input_shape) {
                                       return(self$output_dim)
                                     }
                                   )
)

# Create layer wrapper function
layer_3D_ROI_pooled <- function(object, List_RoI, output_dim) {
  create_layer(ROI_3D_pooled_Layer, object, list(List_RoI = List_RoI, 
                                                 output_dim = as.integer(output_dim)
  ))
}
```

This is my first attempt with a Keras Custom Layer (using R) so please provide suggestions for improvement.